# How to display the graph after it is stabilized (vis.js)?

Tags: reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am rendering a graph using implementation of vis network as shown [here](https://github.com/crubier/react-graph-vis). Right now the graph is taking some time to stabilize after being rendered. But I want the network to be stabilized before being displayed. I tried using the stabilization options under the physics module, but I could not achieve it.

The following is my Graph Component.

```
import {default as React, Component} from 'react';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import differenceWith from 'lodash/differenceWith';
import vis from 'vis';
import uuid from 'uuid';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {identifier} = props;
    this.updateGraph = this.updateGraph.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      identifier : identifier !== undefined ? identifier : uuid.v4()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.edges = new vis.DataSet();
    this.edges.add(this.props.graph.edges);
    this.nodes = new vis.DataSet();
    this.nodes.add(this.props.graph.nodes);
    this.updateGraph();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let nodesChange = !isEqual(this.nodes.get(), nextProps.graph.nodes);
    let edgesChange = !isEqual(this.edges.get(), nextProps.graph.edges);
    let optionsChange = !isEqual(this.props.options, nextProps.options);
    let eventsChange = !isEqual(this.props.events, nextProps.events);

    if (nodesChange) {
      const idIsEqual = (n1, n2) => n1.id === n2.id;
      const nodesRemoved = differenceWith(this.nodes.get(), nextProps.graph.nodes, idIsEqual);
      const nodesAdded = differenceWith(nextProps.graph.nodes, this.nodes.get(), idIsEqual);
      const nodesChanged = differenceWith(differenceWith(nextProps.graph.nodes, this.nodes.get(), isEqual), nodesAdded);
      this.patchNodes({nodesRemoved, nodesAdded, nodesChanged});
    }

    if (edgesChange) {
      const edgesRemoved = differenceWith(this.edges.get(), nextProps.graph.edges, isEqual);
      const edgesAdded = differenceWith(nextProps.graph.edges, this.edges.get(), isEqual);
      this.patchEdges({edgesRemoved, edgesAdded});
    }

    if (optionsChange) {
      this.Network.setOptions(nextProps.options);
    }

    if (eventsChange) {
      let events = this.props.events || {}
      for (let eventName of Object.keys(events))
        this.Network.off (eventName, events[eventName])

      events = nextProps.events || {}
      for (let eventName of Object.keys(events))
        this.Network.on (eventName, events[eventName])
    }

    return false;
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateGraph();
  }

  patchEdges({edgesRemoved, edgesAdded}) {
    this.edges.remove(edgesRemoved);
    this.edges.add(edgesAdded);
  }

  patchNodes({nodesRemoved, nodesAdded, nodesChanged}) {
    this.nodes.remove(nodesRemoved);
    this.nodes.add(nodesAdded);
    this.nodes.update(nodesChanged);
  }

  updateGraph() {
    let options = this.props.options;

    this.Network = new vis.Network(
            this.refs.nw,
      Object.assign(
        {},
        this.props.graph,
        {
          edges: this.edges,
          nodes: this.nodes
        }
      ),
      options
    );


    if (this.props.getNetwork) {
      this.props.getNetwork(this.Network)
    }

    // Add user provided events to network
    let events = this.props.events || {};
    for (let eventName of Object.keys(events)) {
      this.Network.on(eventName, events[eventName]);
    }
  }

  render(){
        return (<div ref="nw" style={{width:'100%' , height: '480px'}}/>);
    }
}

Graph.defaultProps = {
  graph: {},
  style: { width: '100%', height: '480px' }
};
Graph.propTypes = {
  graph: PropTypes.object,
  style: PropTypes.object,
  getNetwork: PropTypes.func
};

export default Graph;
```

This is my options object

```
let options = {
layout: {
    hierarchical: false
},
autoResize: false,
edges: {
  smooth: false,
  color: '#000000',
  width: 0.5,
  arrows: {
    to: {
      enabled: true,
      scaleFactor: 0.5
    }
  }
}
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you tried enabling stabilization without success. The following in the options should work:

```
physics: {
  stabilization: {
    enabled: true,
    iterations: 5000    // YMMV
  }
}
```

Is this different from what you tried?

Comment: I have turned off stablization, is there any other way I can still stablize my graph before it appears? :)